# Why am I not able to deploy erc721 contract on the Hedera testnet?

Tags: solidity, hedera-hashgraph

This is the contract code, I am trying to deploy using Remix.

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity 0.8.19;
    
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.7.3/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
    
    contract NonFungibleToken721 is ERC721 {
        uint256 private _nextTokenId;
    
        constructor()
            ERC721("NonFungibleToken721", "NFT721")
        {}
    
        function safeMint(address to) public {
            uint256 tokenId = _nextTokenId++;
            _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        }
    }
```

But I am getting an error.

```json
creation of NonFungibleToken721 errored: Returned error: 

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"[ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {\"id\":942825022793,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"params\":[\"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\"],\"method\":\"eth_sendRawTransaction\"} {\n  \"code\": -32603,\n  \"message\": \"Non-200 status code: '400'\",\n  \"data\": {\n    \"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\",\n    \"id\": 942825022793,\n    \"error\": {\n      \"code\": -32003,\n      \"name\": \"gasLimit too low\",\n      \"message\": \"[Request ID: 48598b02-fb92-4fd9-865c-f53abc75c1f9] Transaction gas limit provided '107821' is insufficient of intrinsic gas required '173148'\"\n    }\n  },\n  \"stack\": \"{\\n  \\\"code\\\": -32603,\\n  \\\"message\\\": \\\"Non-200 status code: '400'\\\",\\n  \\\"data\\\": {\\n    \\\"jsonrpc\\\": \\\"2.0\\\",\\n    \\\"id\\\": 942825022793,\\n    \\\"error\\\": {\\n      \\\"code\\\": -32003,\\n      \\\"name\\\": \\\"gasLimit too low\\\",\\n      \\\"message\\\": \\\"[Request ID: 48598b02-fb92-4fd9-865c-f53abc75c1f9] Transaction gas limit provided '107821' is insufficient of intrinsic gas required '173148'\\\"\\n    }\\n  },\\n  \\\"stack\\\": \\\"Error: Non-200 status code: '400'\\\\n    at new i (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-3.js:16:10940)\\\\n    at s (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-3.js:16:13880)\\\\n    at Object.internal (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-3.js:16:14490)\\\\n    at u (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background-0.js:7:49871)\\\\n    at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background-0.js:7:50970\\\\n    at async chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-4.js:19:37935\\\"\\n}\\n  at new i (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-3.js:16:10940)\\n  at s (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-3.js:16:13880)\\n  at Object.internal (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-3.js:16:14490)\\n  at u (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background-0.js:7:49871)\\n  at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background-0.js:7:50970\\n  at async chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-4.js:19:37935\"\n}","id":3108014185866110}
```

I'm trying to deploy an ERC721 contract to the Hedera Testnet.

Comment: The following part of the error message tells you what needs to change: `Transaction gas limit provided '107821' is insufficient of intrinsic gas required '173148'`

Comment: you can manually set the gas to the required amounts in Remix (or other methods of deployment). when you do not do so gas estimation is used, and it looks like in your particular case the estimated amount was incorrect, and thus I recommend overriding it.

Comment: thanks bro , fixed this already by increasing the gas , forgot to update here . I appreciate the response !